# What is a failproof method for testing a GPIO pin?

Tags: gpio, temperature, ds18b20, 1-wire

So, basically, I've been trying to get my raspberry pi to get the room temperature from a DS18B20 1-wire temperature sensor.

I've read only GPIO 4 is capable of this, and I think for some reason GPIO 4 is not working.

I've tried connecting the sensor there, it is connected as it should, I've been checking the connections since I connected the sensor and couldn't read it...

I've tried connecting an led (using the proper resitor) to GPIO 4 and using wiringpi to turn it on and off, but I got nothing...

My question is, is there a way I can know for sure if the pin is okay and it is just some software issue?

NOTE: I don't really know how this is supposed to work, but when I do:

```
~ $ cd /sys/class/gpio
~ $ ls
```

What I get is:

```
export  gpio17  gpio18  gpio21  gpio22  gpio23  gpio24  gpio25  gpiochip0  unexport
```

The GPIO 4 doesn't show up... Now, I don't know if only the pins in use show, but if that's the case, none of the above should show, because i'm not using any pins right now...

EDIT: I have connected the DS18B20 like it says in the datasheet, like in this picture:
[image: DS18B20 Pinout]

For the modules I have loaded:

```
modprobe w1-gpio
modprobe w1-therm
```

Superuser privileges, obviously.

I also tried:

```
modprobe w1-gpio pullup=1
modprobe w1-therm super_pullup=1
```

When I try:

```
sudo echo "4" > /sys/class/gpio/export
```

I get:

```
echo: write error: Device or resource busy
```

Just tried the pigpio test program and the results are:

```
Skipped non-user gpios: 0 1 28 29 30 31 
Tested user gpios: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
Failed user gpios: None
```

I assume it is supposed to skip those non-user pins, right? Other than that I have no doubts about all the pins working... Which intrigues me, because I still can't read temperature...

I'm at work, I will take the pi home and test it there again with a simple LED turning on and OFF, if I discover anything, I will post it here...

I've been experimenting a lot with the pi, it is probably cluttered with stuff I wanted to test but never really used, do you think it would be wise to try a fresh Raspbian install?

Comment: How have you connected the DS18B20?  Which modules have you loaded to read the sensor?

Comment: The connections seem to be correct.  wiringPi has a pintest program which should be in the installation directory somewhere.  [pigpio](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.htlm) has a similar [gpio test script](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Shell_code).  DISCONNECT everything from the gpios for these tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

I found online that I had to change the raspi.list file to read "deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy main untested" and then run apt-get update and apt-get upgrade.

Then running:

```
sudo modprobe w1-gpio
sudo modprobe w1-therm
cd /sys/bus/w1/devices
ls
:devices listed here, serial number should be something started with 28-0000:
```

After trying this, I was successful and I can read the 3 sensors.

I'm posting this answer as a reference if someone bumps into this question, thank you all for your help anyway :)

Comment: The file to edit is located at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list`, and the first line should read (after editing) `deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy main untested`. However, this didn't solve the original issue for me :(

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when working on a friend's model-B pi. We tried simply turning on an LED with GPIO 4 as you did and nothing happened. Fortunately, we found a solution [here](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/03/raspberry-pi-1-wire-digital-thermometer-sensor/).

We ended up having to edit the /boot/config.txt file and added the line at the bottom of it:

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=4
```

Then rebooted, and were able to find the sensor and read from it. Hope this helps!

Comment: I know thanks comments are poo-poo'ed by this did this worked for me. THANKS! I had everything working before, without doing this, but after fiddling with things with the power on, it stopped reading them, and I thought I'd fried my pins. Phew!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have loaded the kernel modules for 1-wire:
`sudo modprobe w1-gpio pullup=1` and `sudo modprobe w1-therm`.

GPIO4 should show up if you export that pin: `echo “4” > /sys/class/gpio/export` and `echo “in” > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/direction`.

Path to 1-wire data is something like `/sys/bus/w1/devices/xx-xxxxxxxxxx/w1_slave`.

Comment: It is probably better to use an external pull-up to 3V3.  I think 4K7 is normally used.  The internal pull-ups are quite weak at circa 50K.

Comment: I will try this. @joan I have used the external pull up, 4k7 resistor

Comment: I get this when i try that echo: echo: write error: Device or resource busy as for the diection, i get: -bash: /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/direction: No such file or directory